# robot_localization IMU TF

Tags: imu, navigation, transform, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
If I use robot_localization with [9 Degrees of Freedom - Razor IMU](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10736), do I need to provide TF between base link and imu link? Is TF between base_link and imu_link important for robot_localization internal processing?

Since this IMU uses three different chips for an accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer, which sensor's location will determine the TF value?

Based on this [Q &A](https://answers.ros.org/question/9957/what-frame_id-to-put-in-a-sensor_msgsimu-message/), we may need to mount IMU to be aligned with base_link. In that case, how should I align this IMU due to three separate chips locations in the PCB?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270378/robot_localization-imu-tf/) by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-08-08**:
have you had this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you need a transform. Your IMU could be e.g. rotated 90 degree by the z axis, the robot_localization node needs to know that.

Since the IMU is all about rotation and not translation the exact offset between all sensors probably doesn't matter, so just use the center of the razor board.

The [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof#Coordinate_Frames) explains on how to align the razor imu (connector to the front, parts upwards).

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0